# Windows 2008 R2 Offline Files via command line

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, offline-files

I would like to enabled Offline Files on my Windows 2008 computer so I can access a remote share even when it is gone. Is there a way I can configure this via command line, rather than going through the SyncCenter GUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here:
[Synchronizing Offline Files from the command line](http://blogs.technet.com/b/filecab/archive/2007/05/01/synchronizing-offline-files-from-the-command-line.aspx)